# Can't get '.' when it is the last character in input type number

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do i retrieve the text value of my input type number?

I can retrieve the value just fine when it's a valid number

```
1.23 //returns 1.23
1 //returns 1
```

But when the last character is '.'. I can't seem to get it.

```
2. //returns 2
```

Want it to return `2.`

**HTML:**

```
<input type="number" id="size" step="0.001"></td>
```

**JS:**

```
$("#size").val();
```

Comment: Why should it return `2.`? `2.` is the same as `2.0` which is the same as `2`

Comment: If you want to get `2.`, use `text` as type.

Comment: You will have to set your input type to "text" but then your steeping will not work. and you will have to write a function manually for that

Comment: @Andreas actually it isn't, and it makes this question more valuable: https://jsfiddle.net/ptgkfk68/

Comment: @Kaiido The code at linked jsfiddle renders `10` when `10.` in the `.value`.

Comment: @guest271314 yes I never said it doesn't. But `10.0 !== 10` for `input[type=number].value`. So why does `"10."` equals `"10"` rather than `"10.0"`? It is important to keep precision, so it sounds normal `"10.0"` is kept as is, but I think the `"10."` case is debatable.

Comment: @Kaiido Can you clarify what you are trying to convey? Do you mean comparing strings?

Comment: @Kaiido That comparison returns different results when using `.valueAsNumber`

Comment: @guest271314 unless you call `input.valueAsNumber` we are talking about strings yes. And nobody talked about valueAsNumber for now. jquery `val` uses `value`, so we can assume OP is retrieving value as string.

Comment: @Kaiido One potential approach to get the value `"2."` when `"2."` is `.value` of `<input>` is to get the value of the `.textContent` of the elements' `ShadowDOM` which renders the `"2."`, though accessing the `ShadowDOM` attached to the `<input type="number">` element using `DOM` methods available at browser is not possible  as far as am aware of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `type="number"` you probably get a numbered version of the input value.

If you try `Number('13.')` in Javascript you get 13

Change it to `type="text"` and you should get the entire value.

Comment: but using `type="text"` will let other characters to be inputted.

Comment: Yup. That is always the case and this in where validations come in place. You can have a custom validation using regex pattern for your desired set of inputs

Comment: May be this regex will help. This restricts your input to only number upto 2 decimal places. `decimalRegex = /^\d+(\.\d{0,1})?$/;`

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
parseFloat($("#size").val());
```

all results:

```
parseFloat('1.23') // return 1.23;
parseFloat('1') // return 1;
parseFloat('2.') // return 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for '.' using string functions. If it does not exist, then append it.
Else you have to use input type text.

Comment: How do you get the text of the element at `ShadowDOM` which renders `2.`?